# Performance: Sorting Slice vs Sorting Type (of Slice) with Sort implementation

Tags: sorting, go, slice

I was playing with some code challenges and found that custom sort (implementation of sort interface) work much faster than just for raw structure of slices. Why is that? Does slice conversion to type do some magic (like converting to slice of pointers to structs)?

I made some code to test my hipotesis

```
package sortingexample

import (
    "sort"
    "testing"
)

// Example of struct we going to sort.

type Point struct {
    X, Y int
}

// --- Struct / Raw Data
var TestCases = []Point{
    {10, 3},
    {10, 4},
    {10, 35},
    {10, 5},
    {10, 51},
    {10, 25},
    {10, 59},
    {10, 15},
    {10, 22},
    {10, 91},
}

// Example One - Sorting Slice Directly
// somehow - slowest way to sort it.
func SortSlice(points []Point) {
    sort.Slice(points, func(i, j int) bool {
        return points[i].Y < points[j].Y
    })
}

func BenchmarkSlice(b *testing.B) {
    tmp := make([]Point, len(TestCases))
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        copy(tmp, TestCases)
        SortSlice(tmp)
    }
}

// Example Two - Sorting Slice Directly
// much faster performance
type Points []Point

// Sort interface implementation
func (p Points) Less(i, j int) bool { return p[i].Y < p[j].Y }
func (p Points) Len() int           { return len(p) }
func (p Points) Swap(i, j int)      { p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i] }

func SortStruct(points []Point) {
    sort.Sort(Points(points))
}

func BenchmarkStruct(b *testing.B) {
    tmp := make([]Point, len(TestCases))
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        copy(tmp, TestCases)
        SortStruct(tmp)
    }
}

// --- Pointers
var TestCasesPoints = []*Point{
    &Point{10, 3},
    &Point{10, 4},
    &Point{10, 35},
    &Point{10, 5},
    &Point{10, 51},
    &Point{10, 25},
    &Point{10, 59},
    &Point{10, 15},
    &Point{10, 22},
    &Point{10, 91},
}

// Example Three - Sorting Slice of Pointers

func SortSlicePointers(points []*Point) {
    sort.Slice(points, func(i, j int) bool {
        return points[i].Y < points[j].Y
    })
}

func BenchmarkSlicePointers(b *testing.B) {
    tmp := make([]*Point, len(TestCasesPoints))
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        copy(tmp, TestCasesPoints)
        SortSlicePointers(tmp)
    }
}

// Example Four - Sorting Struct (with Slice of pointers beneath it)
type PointsPointer []*Point

func (pp PointsPointer) Less(i, j int) bool { return pp[i].Y < pp[j].Y }
func (pp PointsPointer) Len() int           { return len(pp) }
func (pp PointsPointer) Swap(i, j int)      { pp[i], pp[j] = pp[j], pp[i] }

func SortStructOfSlicePointers(points []*Point) {
    sort.Sort(PointsPointer(points))
}

func BenchmarkStructOfSlicePointers(b *testing.B) {
    tmp := make([]*Point, len(TestCasesPoints))

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        copy(tmp, TestCasesPoints)
        SortStructOfSlicePointers(tmp)
    }
}
```

And here are results...

```
> go test -bench=.
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkSlice-4                     3000000           542 ns/op
BenchmarkStruct-4                    5000000           318 ns/op
BenchmarkSlicePointers-4             5000000           280 ns/op
BenchmarkStructOfSlicePointers-4     5000000           321 ns/op
```

It's obvious that sorting a slice of pointers will work faster, but why does custom sort implementation faster? Are there any resources I can read about it?

Comment: The less functions should compare for less, not less than or equal.  The fastest of the four tests uses sort.Slice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 1) OK (it's an accident). 2) Everything faster if you don't need to move big chunks of memory, pointer faster by default, Question was about `[]Structs`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The general [`sort.Slice()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Slice) and [`sort.SliceStable()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#SliceStable) functions work on any slices. You have to pass your slice value as an `interface{}` value, and the implementation has to use reflection (the [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package) to access its elements and length, and to perform the swaps of elements.

In contrast, when you implement the [`sort.Interface`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface) type yourself, in your implementation you have access to the static type of your slice, and you can provide the implementation of the `sort.Interface` without relfection, this is what will make it faster.

So if performance is critical / important, always provide the `sort.Interface` implementation yourself. If the slices are small or performance is not important, you may use the more convenient `sort.Slice()` function.

Answer (score 0):

adding the run output with allocations looks like the interface/struct method is better there too.

```
❯ go version
go version go1.17.1 darwin/amd64
❯ go test -bench=. -benchmem
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: github.com/timescale/promscale/pkg/api/parser/json/test
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-8950HK CPU @ 2.90GHz
BenchmarkSlice-12                        3533616               319.6 ns/op            88 B/op          3 allocs/op
BenchmarkStruct-12                       9157018               126.0 ns/op            24 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkSlicePointers-12                6643446               167.1 ns/op            56 B/op          2 allocs/op
BenchmarkStructOfSlicePointers-12        9004021               124.1 ns/op            24 B/op          1 allocs/op
PASS
ok      github.com/timescale/promscale/pkg/api/parser/json/test 5.425s
```